# 32bit VM only supports 64bit instructions

Tags: 32bit-64bit, virtualization

Is it possible that my 32bit (i686) VM does not support 32bit instructions?

I am getting a SIGILL in the 32bit ipp library when run on a test VM.

lscpu:

`Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        64-bit
CPU(s):                2
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
CPU socket(s):         2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1995.192
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K`

Does the "op-mode: 64bit" imply that this VM only supports 64bit instructions? My (64bit) baremetal desktop reports: `CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit` which implies to me that `64bit` is not a superset of `32bit` and that my i686 VM is actually not capable of executing 32bit instructions?

Is this logic correct? If so am I right in the suspicion that this is the reason the 32bit ipp SIGILL's (it calls a 32bit instruction and fails?)

Comment: Please provide more details. What VM platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can run an 32-bit OS inside your VM at all, your virtual CPU supports Intel 32 bit instructions. Most likely it is bugs in your library that cause it to SIGILL. Attaching a debugger and looking at the actual instruction bytes (opcode) should sched more light on what might've gone wrong.

Answering your second question: no, Intel 64 (or AMD64) is not a strict superset of Intel 32 architecture. Certain instructions are not encodable or have assumed a new meaning. The most prominent example are 0x40-0x4F which were INC and DEC on 32-bit systems but are parts of opcode (so called REX prefix) in Inlte 64 architecture. But in the case of using a VM that abstracts host architecture from target architecture, it really should not matter.